# Implementing Scalar and Vector Addition for Custom Type with std::transform

Tags: templates, c++11, overloading, typename

This looks to me like a basic problem so apologies in advance for duplicate posts. Not sure what the terminology is though.

I have a class, say `my_data`, for storing numbers. It has the basic constructors etc. and it would be handy to support elementary operations such as adding to the elements, e.g. increasing the values in the data.

This is the most elementary way to describe the class:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>     
#include <numeric>      
#include <iterator>     

template <typename T>

class my_data {

public:
  my_data  (const my_data& other);
  my_data& operator=(const my_data& rhs);
  my_data  (const size_t bsize) { my_datavec.resize(bsize); }
  my_data  (std::vector<T> init) { my_datavec = init; }  

  template <typename U>
  void add(const U addition) {
    std::transform(my_datavec.begin(), my_datavec.end(), 
                   my_datavec.begin(), 
                   bind2nd(std::plus<T>(), addition) );
  }

  template <typename U>
  void add(const my_data<U> addition) {
     std::transform(my_datavec.begin(), my_datavec.end(), 
                    addition.my_datavec.begin(),
                    my_datavec.begin(), 
                    std::plus<T>() );
  }  

  void print() {    
    std::ostream_iterator<T> out_it (std::cout,", ");
    std::copy(my_datavec.begin(), my_datavec.end(), out_it);
  }

protected:
  std::vector<T> my_datavec;

};

int main() {

  std::vector<int> int_test({1,2,3});
  my_data<int> a(int_test);

  a.add(2);
  a.print();

  a.add(a);
  a.print();

  return(0);

}
```

The problem starts when I want to add the values of one object to the values of another (abusing the fact here that they are the same size to omit checks):

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 template2.cpp -o template2
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_function.h:741:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/string:50,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/locale_classes.h:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/ios_base.h:43,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ios:43,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/ostream:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.7/iostream:40,
             from template2.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/backward/binders.h: In instantiation of ‘std::binder2nd<_Operation> std::bind2nd(const _Operation&, const _Tp&) [with _Operation = std::plus<int>; _Tp = my_data<int>]’:
template2.cpp:20:5:   required from ‘void my_data<T>::add(U) [with U = my_data<int>; T = int]’
template2.cpp:45:10:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.7/backward/binders.h:170:57: error: invalid cast from type ‘const my_data<int>’ to type ‘_Arg2_type {aka int}’
```

The code of adding two `my_data` objects together does not seem to be used. Of course `<typename U>` can be objects of type `X` as well as `my_data<X>` but how do I let the compiler know when to use the second version of `add()`?

My current version of the program uses

```
void add (const bisArray<U> addition, const std::true_type&)
```

for adding an element and

```
void add (const bisArray<U> addition, const std::false_type&)
```

for adding a `my_data` object (the calls are `a.add(2, std::is_arithmetic<int>::type() );` for adding an element and `a.add(a, std::is_arithmetic<my_data<int>>::type() );` for adding a `my_data` object).

It is not really a solution though because there is nothing to prevent the occurrence of the calls `a.add( a , std::is_arithmetic<int>::type() );` and `a.add( 2 , std::is_arithmetic<my_data<int>>::type() );` which lead to a segmentation fault.

Is there a mechanism to resolve this more elegantly?

Comment: In the second overload of `add`, you use the overload of `std::transform` that expects a binary predicate. But you are passing `bind2nd(std::plus<T>(), addition)` which is a unary predicate. It seems you should be using plain `std::plus<T>()` there.

Comment: If you prefer to add 2 my_data objects better we can declare an operator over loaded function for +(add) in class, it will be a replacement for your second add function in class now

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thanks -- that was a copy-paste error -- fixed!

Comment: With this fix, your code compiles. Problem solved, then?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik my code selects the `void add(const U addition)` version of `add()` for adding a value of type `U` as well as for adding a `my_data` object of type `my_data<U>`. Still a bit baffled why that does not happen in @5gon12eder 's code.

Comment: [No it doesn't](http://rextester.com/MSYX82400). It works as expected.

Comment: So it does! Sorry, I was confused because I still got an error: `template2.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'my_data<int>::my_data(my_data<int> const&)'
` `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. I did have to remove the copy ctor for it to compile, but that was not the original error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.  The most immediate reason for your code not compiling was already pointed out by  [Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670129/igor-tandetnik) in the comments.

I'll start in “declaration order” which is not the order of severity:

1. The correct header to `#include` for `std::size_t` is not `stdlib.h` but `cstddef`.  (Generally, don't `#include` the `*.h` but the `c*` versions.)
2. You probably want to add a default constructor that initializes your type with an empty vector.
3. You probably want to make the constructors that take one argumrnt `explicit`.  It avoids bad surprises when an integer suddenly converts to a `my_data`.
4. The constructor that takes a `std::vector<T>` needlessly makes a copy of its argument.  At the very least, you should `std::move` it into its destination.  You might also want to consider providing an overload for `const std::vector<T>&` (which does a copy) and `std::vector<T>&&` (which does a move).
5. Prefer initializer lists over assignment in the constructor.
6. Generally prefer C++11's uniform initialization syntax (`{ … }`).
7. Use C++11 lambdas instead of the legacy binders.  It's more readable and at least as efficient.
8. Consider overloading operators `+=` and `<<` instead of providing named member functions.
9. Your vector addition needs a size-check.  `std::transform` cannot tell how long the second and third ranges are.
10. The addition functions shouldn't make a needless copy of their argument.
11. In the vector addition's `std::transform` call, a binary function should be provided.  Since you have templated the function, neither `std::plus<T>` nor `std::plus<U>` are applicable.  Use a lambda that adds a `T` and a `U`.  This will also be more efficient if, for example `T = std::string` and `U = char *`.

Let's put all this together:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class my_data
{

public:

  my_data()
  {
  }

  explicit my_data (const std::size_t size)
  {
    data.resize(size);
  }

  explicit my_data(const std::vector<T>& init) : data {init}
  {
  }

  explicit my_data(std::vector<T>&& init) : data {std::move(init)}
  {
  }

  template<typename U>
  void
  operator+=(const U& a)
  {
    std::transform(data.begin(),
                   data.end(),
                   data.begin(),
                   [&a](const T& b){ return a + b; });
  }

  template<typename U>
  void
  operator+=(const my_data<U>& other)
  {
    if (other.data.size() != this->data.size())
      throw std::invalid_argument {"incompatible sizes"};
    std::transform(data.begin(),
                   data.end(),
                   other.data.begin(),
                   data.begin(),
                   [](const T& a, const U& b){ return a + b; });
  }

  friend
  std::ostream&
  operator<<(std::ostream& os, const my_data& md)
  {
    std::ostream_iterator<T> outit {os, ", "};
    std::copy(md.data.begin(), md.data.end(), outit);
    return os;
  }

protected:

  std::vector<T> data {};
};

int main() {
  std::vector<int> inttest {1, 2, 3};
  my_data<int> a {inttest};
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  a += 2;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
  a += a;
  std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3, 
3, 4, 5, 
6, 8, 10,
```

One more thing that you might wish to address is the superfluous trailing comma in the output.

Comment: That's brilliant! The my_data example was a simplified version of my code (to isolate the problem) but I can apply most of your suggestions -- thanks! Mind you I still don't understand why the compiler did not select the right add() in my initial code and does in your += code?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about why a compiler produces a specific error message for an ill-formed program.  Imagine how difficult it can be for the compiler to guess what you expected from your code if it cannot compile it.  The overload is unambiguous in this case because `let U = int in my_type<U>` is a better match than `let U = my_type<int> in U`.  This is because while both sets of type are infinitely countable, the latter is s true superset of the former.