# overload resolution fails for derived class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overloading, overload-resolution

I am using a class mArray, which implements numerical data containers with variable dimensionality

```
template <typename T>
   class mArray<T>: {
     ...
     std::vector<T> my_data;
   }
```

Another class `mImage` inherits from `mArray` and provides image-specific operations, and another class `mDcmImage` inherits from `mImage` and provides format-specific functions.

I thought this was a very clean way to separate different types of functionality.

One example or `mArray` functionality: element-wise addition:

```
// add a mArray to the data [1]
template <typename U>
void operator+= (const mArray<U>& other) {
    if (other.getSizes() != getSizes())
        throw std::invalid_argument {"incompatible sizes"};
    else {
        std::transform (my_data.begin(),
                        my_data.end(),
                        my_data.begin(),
                        my_data.begin(),
                        []( const T &a, const U &b) { return a+b; } );
    }
    return;
}

// add an element to the data [2]
template <typename U>
void operator+= (const U& rhs) {
    assert (!std::is_arithmetic<U>::value);
    std::transform (my_data.begin(),
                    my_data.end(),
                    my_data.begin(),
                    [&rhs]( const T &lhs) { return lhs+rhs; } );
    return;
}
```

(`getSizes()` is an `mArray` function)
But now my code loads a `mDcmImage<int>` from a file, and when I use

```
typedef int intensity;
mDcmImage<intensity> im1 ("/tmp/test1.im");
mDcmImage<intensity> im2 ("/tmp/test2.im");
im1 += im2;
```

then I get the following error:

```
mArray.hpp required from ‘struct mArray<T>::operator+=(const U&) 
           [with U = mDcmImage<int>; T = int]::<lambda(const int&)>’|
mArray.hpp required from ‘void mArray<T>::operator+=(const U&) 
           [with U = mDcmImage<int>; T = int]’|
  test.cpp required from here|
mArray.hpp error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘lhs + rhs’|
```

In other words: although I coded the addition of another `mArray` as well as the addition of one value, when I call the `+=` operator in the main program to add two arrays together, it uses the `+=` implementation for a single value.

I have tried several things, such as

- using `std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value >::type*` for the value version of `operator+=` -- not allowed because `operator+=` takes strictly 1 argument
- defining both versions of `operator+=` for `mImage` and `mDcmImage` as well -- at those levels it also uses the wrong implementation.

In a [simplified example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745566) the right version of the operator **is** selected -- why not now? I cannot see why the overload resolution fails here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After template argument deduction, the second version becomes a perfect match:

```
template <typename U> void operator+= (const U& rhs); // U = mDcmImage<int>
```

compared to the first version, which requires a conversion from `mDcmImage` to `mArray`:

```
template <typename U> void operator+= (const mArray<U>& other); // U = int
```

so it is selected by overload resolution.

---

The simplest fix is probably to modify the single-value version to just take a `T` and rely on implicit conversions:

```
void operator+= (const T& rhs);
```

SFINAE is also possible, for instance in the return type:

```
template <typename U> 
typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<U>::value>::type operator+= (const U& rhs);
```

Comment: Why not test based on being compatible with an `mArray<U> const&`?  If compatible, use first, if not, use second.

Comment: @Yakk `is_arithmetic` is the test used in the OP, which also limits the class to numerical data, so I just went for it.

Comment: Ha! I like the first solution of just removing the `<typename U>` because it works and is much simpler than how I thought about it! What would be the benefit of the SFINAE one?

Comment: @alle_meije The conversions performed are different in the two cases (one converts the operand to `T`, one may not), so in some corner cases there will be differences. [A simplified example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50f847f9d4c4e441).

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z>
  std::false_type inherits_from_template_helper(...);
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Us>
  std::true_type  inherits_from_template_helper(Z<Us...>&&);

}
// C++14 has this in `std`:
template<class T>using decay_t=typename std::decay<T>::type;
template<template<class...>class Z, class T>
using inherits_from_template
  = decltype(
    details::inherits_from_template_helper<Z>(
      std::declval<decay_t<T>>()
    )
  );

template<class T>
using is_mArray = inherits_from_template<mArray, T>;
```

is a traits test that says "is the type passed in basically an `mArray`

Now use SFINAE or tag dispatching to dispatch to correct += depending on if your argument is an `mArray`.

```
template<class U>
mArray<T>& operator+=(U&& u) {
  increase_by( std::forward<U>(u), is_mArray<U>{} );
  return *this;
}
template<class U>
void increase_by( U const& u, std::false_type /* is_mArray<U> */ ) {
  // scalar addition code
}
template<class U>
void increase_by( mArray<U> const& u, std::true_type /* is_mArray<U> */ ) {
  // mArray addition code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had not though about doing it like this. The `+=` operator cannot take more than 1 argument but of course it can call functions that do.

Comment: after trying this, it turns out that for the code in the post, i.e. when using a `mDcmImage` rather than an `mArray`, then the test returns `is_mArray<mDcmImage<int>&>` aka `std::integral_constant<bool,false>` and no substitution can be found?

Comment: @alle ah.  Sorry I need a decay.  Adding...  should be fixed.